# Laravel orderBy on with

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

I have problem with eloquent query. I am using one to Many Relationship to get 'MenuItems' With the 'Menu'.
I want to get all menuItems of a particular menu in sorted by 'sort_order' field
Using the code below:

```
Menu::where('slug', 'main-navigation')->with('MenuItems')->orderBy('MenuItems.sort_order', 'asc')->get();
```

It is not working, is it possible to do it with eloquent? If yes then how?

Comment: yes it is possible to do with eloquent. first have with than where

Comment: @kamlesh.bar still it is not working

Comment: have you set proper relationship do you have function MenuItems in your Model.

Comment: Yup i have written MenuItems function in model to specify the relationship

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
 Menu::where('slug', 'main-navigation')->with([
     'MenuItems' => function($query) {
          $query->orderBy('MenuItems.sort_order', 'asc')
     }
])->get();
```

This will sort all the menu-items under each menu as per sort_order.